# Need a SQL statement to filter rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, relational-database

There is a table which look like this:
[image]

I need to retrieve only highlighted records. And I need a query which should work on bigger table where are millions of records are exists.

**Criteria:**
There are 4 sets, 1st and 3rd have the similar values but 2nd and 4th sets have different values

**Edit:**
I made slight modification in the table( ID column added). How can we achieve the same with the ID column?

[image]

Comment: Nice.  And I want a new Mac book, but without showing effort no one will buy it for me.

Comment: Won't `select cola,colb from table where cola in (2,4) `work

Comment: What is the criteria for a row to be highlighted?

Comment: Not able to see image due to firewall. See this for more details as it does not only apply to code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Dear @Deepak Either you need very basic understanding of SQL. here people come up with much bigger issues than this one which can be solved by an entry level programmer. Your requirement too is not understandable that the records would only have this pattern or there may be varied, So be clear about the things you want and try it yourself. If it seems complex then put it here with a brief explanation as the people here are coders not Ginnie who can assume of all your million rows. And this would also save you from disaster. Thanks

Comment: @TheGameiswar if there are millions of rows how will u find them?

Comment: @Richard you see there are 4 sets, 1st and 3rd have the similar values but 2nd and 4th sets have different values

Comment: Thats right,i think Richard asked the right question

Comment: @MaulikModi I have some knowledge about SQL. The real table much complex and bigger, I made this for the simplicity, I just need to element this pattern of records

Comment: This would have been a great question,if you could have explained the criteria first

Comment: @Deepak But what we need is pattern dude. What can be pattern here? Tell us the pattern

Comment: OK, what makes the 1st and 3rd sets different to the 2nd and 4th? (I can see a pattern – see TheGameiswar's comment – but is that all the pattern that there is in just a example of the data?)

Comment: @MaulikModi check first 3 rows, 3 of them are duplicates, then row 4 to 6 colB has two different values, I need to return only this kind of set where 1 or more different value exists in the set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> return only this kind of set where 1 or more different value exists in the set

```
create table #ab
(
col1a int,
colb char(2)
)

insert into #ab
values
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(2,'c'),
(2,'c')

select id,col1a,colb
from #ab
where col1a in (
Select col1a from #ab group by col1a having count (distinct colb)>1)
```

Regarding the performance over millions of rows,i would probably check the execution plan and deal with it.with my sample data set and my query ,Distinct sort takes nearly 40% of cost..with millions of rows,it can probably go to tempdb as well..so i suggest below index which can eliminate more rows

```
create index nci on #ab(colb)
include(col1a)
```

Comment: Glad it helped you,if you could post DDL,DML(test data like the one in my answer) and expected result as text along with explanation and what you have tried.. you will get much faster results

Comment: No I don't want to create index on existing table, I just need to select this kind of rows

Comment: can we do the same when id column also exists in the table. Please check above edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` as it is million rows query.

```
SELECT f.colA,f.colB
FROM
filtertable f
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT colA
FROM filtertable
GROUP BY colA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colB)>1
) f1
ON f.colA = f1.colA
```